# UIButton Image does not scale

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a button with text and image and it looks perfectly fine in IB but when I run the app the images don't scale they are wider than the canvas. How does this happen? I tried several modes like "Aspect to fill", and "Scale to Fill" but none of them does anything on the image.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting

```
button.backgroundImage = yourImage;
```

instead of

```
button.image = yourImage;
```

Comment: When I do that I can't place a label (text) on bottom of the image